# 404 not found using Ubuntu sudo apt-get

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu

I recently set up a server with Storm On Demand, and I am trying to install Ruby (and others), but I am getting a 404 Not Found error when I use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full
```

Am I doing something wrong?  Here is a sample of what I am getting back:

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/main ruby1.8-dev 1.8.7.72-3ubuntu0.1
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.169 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xorg/x11-common_7.4~5ubuntu18_all.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.169 80]
```

I am not exactly an expert, but I would really appreciate any help you could give me

Comment: run `apt-get update` like @ShinTakezou suggested.  Your index is out of date.

Comment: Since this is a problem with the OS and with aptitude, I'm recommending migration to [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Linux 9.04 (Jaunty Jackalope) reached [end-of-life on October 23, 2010](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2010-September/000137.html) and thus the repositories for this version have been removed from the primary servers. You can still find the packages on the [archive server](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/), though.

You should upgrade to a more current version as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently you're trying to pull from Jaunty repos, which (to me) means that you're using Jaunty Jackalope (Ubuntu 9.04).

Ubuntu 9.04 hit End of Life in October of 2010, and so Canonical is not obligated to maintain those old repositories anymore; it's very possible that Ruby doesn't exist for Jaunty anymore.  Whether or not those repos exist or not I haven't been able to find out for sure, but there are always options like repo mirrors or [Ubuntu Backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports).  Clever Googling might help.

That being said, using the version of Ruby that comes in any mirror of the 9.04 repos would be a terrible idea because they don't go through Canonical's security review when -- or more properly, **if** -- they get updated.  You will be stuck using most likely outdated (and possibly insecure) versions of Ruby and any related technology (Rails, MySQL, etc).

I realize that a lot of VPS solutions and the like can limit your options on what OS you run on your server, but unless it's *absolutely critical* that you stay on Jaunty or impossible to select a different version from Storm, your best bet would be to upgrade and work with up-to-date repos.  Plus you'll be on an OS that the developers actually provide support for.

Answer (score 0):

It means that resource does not exist (anymore?), or maybe it's mispelled for any reason. Reading http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xorg/ you can search for the file you may be interested in (there something similar, maybe `x11-common_7.4+3ubuntu10_all.deb`?; updating the list with `sudo apt-get update` could fix the wrong file name, but I am not sure if the problem is this.

Comment: It seems that I cannont install anything.....I tried to install a FTP using: sudo apt-get install vsftpd and I got the same result.